# Windows Phone 7's ListPicker control isn't opening up the full selection window

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listpicker

Here's how looks like when idle:

[image]

And here it is, when I tap on it, when it should be popping the full screen selection mode (according to what I've read):

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't seem to be opening the full screen selection mode.

Here is my XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="GameLense.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Width="34" Height="34">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Margin="12 0 0 0" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12 0 0 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border Background="Gold" Width="34" Height="34">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Margin="12 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12 0 0 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Begin Top Bar -->
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/topbarBg.png" Stretch="Fill" />
        <TextBlock Text="Console" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" 
                   Padding="10"/>

        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lstPlatform" 
                            ListPickerMode="Full"
                            Grid.Row="0" CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                            Margin="160 0 10 0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" 
                            FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" />

        <!--End Top Bar -->

    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the set the `ItemCountThreshold="0"` on the ListPicker control in order to immediately enter full screen selection mode.

Answer (score 6):

You can also set `ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"` on your listpicker to fix this up.

Answer (score 1):

The control will be contained by the `Grid.Row` and will abide its size limits. That being said, it won't cross the border of the second row. You need to either have it inside another `Grid.Row` that has a larger height or open it in a popup.

Comment: Nope that's wasn't it. It seems the control has a dependency property `ItemCountThreshold` that it can get to and once it crosses that maximum value, it'll go into full mode. The solution was to set that property to 0 for it to automatically expand. Hope this helps someone out. :)

Comment: I had the same problem, and like Den said the Grid.Row size was limiting the expansion of the ListPicker